# I want to open an activity as bottom sheet dialog

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a button, which onClicked takes to another activity. Now I want the activity to open as bottomDialog. How o do that??

```
 if (success) {

                val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("total_amount",totalAmount)
                startActivity(intent)
                finishAffinity()

              }
```

I want the PaymentActivity mentioned here to be opened as bottomSheet.

Comment: change ```PaymentActivity``` Theme in Manifest```<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />``` this will working like activity as dialog

Comment: I get an error " java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915764/12709358

Comment: Extend your PaymentActivity from BottomSheetDialogFragment instead of AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Check this for bottom sheet dialog it may help you [Open BottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243928/open-an-activity-or-fragment-with-bottom-sheet-deep-linking)

Answer (score 0):

change your Payment Activity to BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
class PaymentActivity : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_payment, container, false)
}
```

}

and you can call it like this,

```
if (success) {

           val b = PaymentActivity()
        b.show(supportFragmentManager, "Hi")

          }
```

Add total amount in Bundle.